# Capture mouse click event in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to create a simple windows form applicaiton in c# which will count the right left clicks from the mouse event. I have copy the following code which detect the click event:

```
private void mouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Mouse clicked");
    }
}
```

And in Form method I add `this.MouseClick += mouseClick;`. My issue is that this function activates every time a click is performed whether is right or left click. Why is that?

Comment: Do you mean "the function is called regardless of button" or "the boolean expression evaluates to true regardless of button"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is by design. `MouseClick` event is raised on every click - doesn't matter was it caused by left or right button.

In order to distinguish left button from right one in this event handler - you have to check `e.Button` property exactly as it was done in your code:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
```

Comment: :D. Yes this if is in m code. However it doenst distinguish the two clicks.

Comment: @JoseRamon Have you tried to debug it? What is the value of `e.Button` in the case of left button click and right one?

Comment: Button -> Left Clicks - 1 Delta - 0 Base x,y, button - left

Comment: @JoseRamon are you getting these values in both left and right clicks?